# Create selectlist with groups

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to create selectlist with items from database grouped by RoomId.

```
 var beds = service.GetApartmentBed(parentId)
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = localizerBedsType[x.BedType.ToString()],
                Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = x.RoomId.ToString()},
            }).ToList();
        AvailableBeds = new SelectList(beds,
                nameof(SelectListItem.Value),
                nameof(SelectListItem.Text),
                BedId,
                nameof(SelectListItem.Group.Name));
```

But when i want to test it in browser, its shows this error:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2lHy.png)

This is value of item:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwRkP.png)

but when i remove last parametr of AvailableBeds it's work well but I don't have groups.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ive done it. Ive need to change last line to "Group.Name"

```
 AvailableBeds = new SelectList(beds,
                    nameof(SelectListItem.Value),
                    nameof(SelectListItem.Text),
                    BedId,
                    "Group.Name");
```